# performSelector and matching cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

If I start something using this:

```
> [self performSelector:@selector(runThis:) 
>    withObject:thisObject  
>    afterDelay:5.0];
```

Which 1 should I later use to cancel it, avoiding "runThis:" from ever running?

```
1> [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

or

```
2> [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
2>    selector:@selector(runThis:) 
2>    object:nil];
```

Not even sure what the difference really is between 1 and 2.

Is #1 canceling ANY/ALL my performSelector's, regardless of their name?

And #2 canceling only one, specifically "runThis:"?

(What if I had 3 different performSelector running "runThis:"?  How would I specify which one to cancel... using #1 or #2?)

#1 seems to correctly cancel things.

#2 doesn't seem to cancel anything.... ever.

Does it matter that I pass thisObject when starting... and nil when canceling?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC either one is fine; the second just gives you finer-grained control.

For #2 you'd have to pass in an object that returns `YES` for `-isEqual:`. `nil` does not mean "anything" for that method, unlike the `NSNotification` stuff.